VSCode Debugger Chrome / React Breakpoints not working
I have this launch.json config:
     {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Debug chrome",
        "url": "http://sandbox.com:3009/pages/index.html",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "userDataDir": "${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/chrome",
      },

In my workspace folder I have a src folder with subfolders src/tools, src/containers, src/components.
My breakpoints work in the tools and containers folder files but not in the components files.  I'm not sure why some breakpoints would work but not others.
